# How is this solved?! is it Essential or Non-Essential?

Tags: punctuation, commas, non-restrictive

while I've been prepping for the SAT using The Ultimate Guide to SAT Grammar Workbook by Erica L. Meltzer I encountered this question:

**Sentence:**
 Before a vaccine was finally discovered by an American ***scientist Jonas Salk*** in 1955, more than 80% of polio patient received help from the foundation

**Question:**

1. NO CHANGE
2. Scientist Jonas Salk,
3. Scientist, Jonas Salk

*4. Scientist, Jonas Salk, (right answer)*

**Comment:**
why isn't the right answer is B since we don't know who the scientist was so it's essential info, also we have before

Comment: The test is meaningless with only the information provided. Is there more than one American scientist in the group being discussed? Is there more than one American scientist named Jonas Salk? There is also a certain level of intention that can only be determined by the author of the sentence. In many ways, the punctuation itself determines, by definition, if something is restrictive or not. Unless the person answering the question is the *author*, the answer is subjective. The only objective answer would be which is the more *common* interpretation. And, for that, there should be evidence.

Comment: Because *an* is there, you need the commas around the name.

Comment: Note that whether it’s essential depends not on meaning or the importance of the information, but only the grammatical structure of the sentence.

Comment: @Xanne The use of *an* does not necessarily make *Jonas Salk* nonrestrictive. It is possible (although unlikely) to still interpret the name as restrictive, in which case the commas should *not* be there.

Comment: My guess is that the multiple-choice options do not capitalize "Scientist," since doing so in the middle of the sentence at issue would be an error. As for why the test considers option 4 the correct answer, I suspect that the person who devised it is checking whether test takers know the standard punctuation treatment in U.S. writing for an appositive—in this case, a construction in which either the more specific "Jonas Salk" or the more general "an American scientist" could stand in for the five words "an American scientist Jonas Salk" without creating problems in coherence or syntax. ...

Comment: ...  Note that it is also possible for "Jonas Salk" in the phrase "the American scientist, Jonas Salk," to function as an appositive—but only if the phrase appears in the context of a prior identification of "the American scientist." That is, it might appear as an appositive in this pair of sentences: "A British scientist and an American scientist walk into a bar. The American scientist, Jonas Salk, asks for a shot." Here "the American scientist" an "Jonas Salk" are interchangeable as replacements for "the American scientist Jonas Salk"; ...

Comment: ... but if the opening sentence in a book began, "Before the American scientist Jonas Salk discovered a vaccine for polio, ..." we couldn't simply say "Before the American scientist discovered a vaccine for polio, ..." although we could say "Before Jonas Salk discovered a vaccine for polio, ..." That's because in that case "Jonas Salk" is not an appositive; it's the subject that "the American scientist" modifies. Because we're dealing in that case with a modified subject, not equivalent alternative subjects, standard U.S. punctuation style rules would oppose putting commas around "Jonas Salk."

Comment: This an exact duplicate of another post: [Are the commas here correct a vaccine was finally discovered by an american](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/383605/are-the-commas-here-correct-a-vaccine-was-finally-discovered-by-an-american?rq=1) ANd Peter Shor there made the same comment I did about using "the". @SvenYargs

Answer (score 2):

The point of the question is not to set history straight but to test one's understanding of parenthetical commas.

Each answer differs in the placement of commas so as to set off the name of the scientist for special consideration. If you imagine the sentence read out loud you can hear how the commas function as pauses in speech to describe secondary details within the text. This can help with comparing one answer to another.